Onchange for <select> with size value
You can notice that if you put size into select - onchange stops working. There is "onfocus" even but it doesn't work either because you have to click outside select every time.
Is there a way to make a working "onchange" event for select with size?
<select name="fruits" size="5">
  <option>banana</option>
  <option>cherry</option>
  <option>strawberry</option>
  <option>durian</option>
  <option>blueberry</option>
</select>


Is it not working? I tried like this in the Codepen. It is working well.
https://codepen.io/junhyunny/pen/jOjaeLJ

Can't reproduce either - Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

What do you mean "reproduce"? In your example, I can see console log when I click the item in select box.

Apparently if you write it inline it doesn't work. Works if you add it with JS though

@JirenCHAD I get it working onchange inline or not

@Junhyunny - My comment was targeted to OP, not you

I get all these 9 triggered when I click anything in Chrome and Firefox.
I strongly recommend to use the addEventListener in any case.


const fruits = document.querySelector('[name=fruits]');

fruits.addEventListener('change', () => console.log('change'));
fruits.addEventListener('input', () => console.log('input'));
fruits.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('click'));

// Also work, but will overwrite the inline event handlers
/* 
fruits.onchange = () => console.log('onchange');
fruits.oninput =  () => console.log('oninput');
fruits.onclick = () => console.log('onclick');
*/
<select name="fruits" size="5"
onchange="console.log('onchange')"
oninput="console.log('oninput')"
onclick="console.log('onclick')"
>
  <option>banana</option>
  <option>cherry</option>
  <option>strawberry</option>
  <option>durian</option>
  <option>blueberry</option>
</select>




you can try Jquery，add this in your HTML:
    <script src="https://cdn.staticfile.net/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
         $(function(){
            $('input[name="fruits"]').change(function (event) {
               console.log(event.data);
            })
         }
    </script>


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
